# Tracking keys with User logged in another Site

Tags: 2009, profiling, tracking

We are trying to track the users visits of certain pages, using profiling with tracking keywords inside some components.

The scenario is Tridion 2009, IIS v6.0, SQL Server 2008 R2, ASP .NET 2.0

The user is logged in an external site, and then is redirected to our site (different web server) with the user data in the **Request**; then I try to use the **userId** as the user considered in the tracking with something like

```
String id = (String)Request["IDENPN"];
User newUser = UserManager.CheckUser(1,0,id);
```

This creates the User in the Broker database, but when the tracking is made, then another **blank** user is created and associated with the tracking key, incrementing the value of tracking of the blank user.

How can I make the Tracking with the User created based on the data of the Request, and not with the user associated with the cookie configured in the **wai_conf**?

It seems a problem with the **WebContext**, but I haven't found the solution.